# C# get filtered list of objects based on derived type

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating an item system for a game. I am trying to store all items in a single `List<Item>` in my `ItemDatabase` class and then pull items that are a specific subclass of type `Item`. Items drawn in my editor are filtered based on the type of items they are and displayed on their appropriate pages. I can not figure out the LINQ query to get this to work.

```
interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

//need to do this because I cannot serialize interface in Unity3D.
class Item : IItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class WeaponItem : Item 
{
    //stuff
}

class ItemDatabase
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class ItemEditor
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var items = ItemDatabase.Items;        
        List<Item> filteredItems = //some way of getting all WeaponItem objects in items list. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is exactly what [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for:

```
List<WeaponItem> filteredItems = items.OfType<WeaponItem>().ToList();
```

The code above will filter the list to items of type `WeaponItem` or items that can be cast to `WeaponItem`.

Comment: And how do I actually get the list of Items because that code returns a list of WeaponItem which it says cannot be cast to a list of Item.

Comment: @Zionmoose I updated the answer. The type of list must be `List<WeaponItem>` and you need to convert it to list using `ToList()`

Comment: I will accept this as answer because it technically is working but I appear to have another unrelated problem with Unity once it recompiles my code it can no longer filter those items even though they still exist.